# Are there any alternatives to flapdoodle for embedded mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

I have tried using flapdoodle's embedded mongodb for integration testing in my SpringBoot application and it runs well locally. However, it fails to run in a docker container when deployed. Are there any alternatives to flapdoodle for embedded mongodb?

Answer (score 2):

There's a Testcontainers library that you can use (https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mongodb/).
It lets you use docker images for your tests, so you can test using actual mongo database.

Comment: Although they are a good alternative they don't well in build pipelines.

Comment: It works perfectly in my pipelines.